# Bibliography : avoid extra spaces (justification) for a single item

Tags: bibliographies

I've been creating my bibliography in the usual way :

```
\nocite*
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{books}
```

`books` being the `.bib` file. How could I avoid something like in this example for [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cj05D.png):

[image]

I've paid attention to other similar issues in there but something like `\raggedright` doesn't satisfy me. I simply would like no justification for the first entry.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the problem is due to the fact that LaTeX treats the URL `www.cssp.com/CD0902/CreatingInnovativeEnvironment` as one word that cannot be split in two lines (just what is happening with my browser right now --- but maybe not yours).

I'd suggest that you use the `url` package, which (among other things) provides line splitting for URLs.  Your LaTeX file should be something like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\hrule
\nocite*
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{books}
\end{document}
```

(where I used the `\hrule` to show where the right margin is) and your `books.bib` should contain something like:

```
@Misc{m1,
  author =       "Dana Baldwin",
  title =        "Creating an environment for innovation",
  howpublished = "\url{www.cssp.com/CD0902/CreatingInnovativeEnvironment}",
  month =        jan,
  year =         2013
}
```

This would be the result:

[image: result]